# Using Record value in chart of Crystal Reports instead of count

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, crystal-reports, sql-server-2012

I have a Report that I've connected to a `Datatable` (Two fields: Choice, Votes) that is connected to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012. The Report shows something like this:

```
Choice            Votes
---------------------------
Option1             11
Option2             8
Option3             4
Option4             7
Option5             5
Option6             6
Option7             1
Option8             2
```

What I want to do is generally simple, just whatever the votes are I want to sum them up and take each percentage with its respective option.
I really have no experience with Reports and their charts, but I was able to add a chart to the report, and in the chart expert, I put

```
On the Change of:
Datatable1.Choice - A
```

Everytime I add the Votes to the "show values" List, it only does the count, which when I run the chart, it shows me each option with the same percentage. I tried looking into summary operations, but `sum` is nowhere to be seen. In the drop down list, all I found was `Count`, and `Distinct count`.

Answer (score 1):

Create this formula:

```
tonumber({Table_field})
```

Go to the Chart Expert and use this formula instead of the field in the 'Show Values' section.